# ASCII Art (Numerical) Output C++

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on my program. The program takes interger input from the user and then my program will print the ASCII art of the input.

**example:**

`Input : 123
 Output :  #  ### ### 
           #    #   # 
           #  ###  ## 
           #  #     # 
           #  ### ###`

The Question is how to print the number next to each other? My program converted it but the Output goes like this 
[image: OutputBroken]

Instead of: `#  ### ### 
           #    #   # 
           #  ###  ## 
           #  #     # 
           #  ### ###`

**Here's my code :**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
int angka,dpn,blk,tng;
string abel,ateng,adep;

cout<<"Masukkan Angka : ";
cin>>angka;

blk = angka % 10;
tng = angka / 10 % 10;
dpn = angka / 100;

switch(blk){
    case 0 : abel = "### \n# # \n# # \n# # \n### "; break;
    case 1 : abel = "# \n# \n# \n# \n# "; break;
    case 2 : abel = "### \n  # \n###  \n#   \n### "; break;
    case 3 : abel = "### \n  # \n ## \n  # \n### "; break;
    case 4 : abel = "# # \n# # \n### \n  # \n  # "; break;
    case 5 : abel = "### \n#   \n### \n  # \n### "; break;
    case 6 : abel = "### \n#   \n### \n# # \n### "; break;
    case 7 : abel = "### \n  # \n  # \n  # \n  # "; break;
    case 8 : abel = "### \n# # \n### \n# # \n### "; break;
    case 9 : abel = "### \n# # \n### \n  # \n### "; break;

}
switch(tng){
    case 1 : ateng = "# \n# \n# \n# \n# "; break;
    case 2 : ateng = "### \n  # \n###  \n#   \n### "; break;
    case 3 : ateng = "### \n  # \n ## \n  # \n### "; break;
    case 4 : ateng = "# # \n# # \n### \n  # \n  # "; break;
    case 5 : ateng = "### \n#   \n### \n  # \n### "; break;
    case 6 : ateng = "### \n#   \n### \n# # \n### "; break;
    case 7 : ateng = "### \n  # \n  # \n  # \n  # "; break;
    case 8 : ateng = "### \n# # \n### \n# # \n### "; break;
    case 9 : ateng = "### \n# # \n### \n  # \n### "; break;

}

switch(dpn){
    case 1 : adep = "# \n# \n# \n# \n# \n"; break;
    case 2 : adep = "### \n  # \n###  \n#   \n### "; break;
    case 3 : adep = "### \n  # \n ## \n  # \n### "; break;
    case 4 : adep = "# # \n# # \n### \n  # \n  # "; break;
    case 5 : adep = "### \n#   \n### \n  # \n### "; break;
    case 6 : adep = "### \n#   \n### \n# # \n### "; break;
    case 7 : adep = "### \n  # \n  # \n  # \n  # "; break;
    case 8 : adep = "### \n# # \n### \n# # \n### "; break;
    case 9 : adep = "### \n# # \n### \n  # \n### "; break;

}


//cout<<dpn<<endl<<blk<<endl<<tng; /*DebugNumber*/

cout<<adep<<ateng<<abel;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: store a vector of strings for the lines and only print them when you know what to print on each line

Comment: Consider using [raw string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) for [readability](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82f97eb8976baae9).

Comment: You probably have to store art in array instead of giving \n. And the iterate over each number print from top to bottom of art.

Comment: Please look at the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [edit] your question so that it doesn't look like a bad hair day. Don't resort to pictures of text.

Comment: @nwp I dont understand why that answer was deleted. I think it was a good one and just missed a note saying that the choosen approach cannot be done with standard c++. I also dont remeber who was the author, so I cannot ask him to undelete it....

Comment: @tobi303 The answer was collecting downvotes and off-topic arguments about how acceptable platform-dependent code is. Such discussions belong in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec), if at all, so it seems like a reasonable decision.

Answer (score 1):

It is not about C++, it is about algorithm. You may for example store the output in the following struct:

```
using Output = std::vector<std::vector<bool>>;
```

and write a function which adds a character into it:

```
void addCharacter(Output o, size_t offset, char theChar) {
  for (int i=0; i<allLines; i++)
    addLineOfChar(o, offset, theChar, i);
}

void addLineOfChar(Output o, size_t offset, char theChar, int line) {
  for (int i=0; i<charsInLine; i++)
    o[offset+i] = data[theChar][line][i];
}
```

And et the end print `true` as `#` and `false` as  (space). But that's just an idea. That's your job to invent the best algorithm.

Comment: I'm Sorry but i cannot understand the code. I'm new to computer programming. But Thanks, maybe I will need it later

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string> 
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

int*arr;                    //'arr' is number of digits
int count=0;                //'count' is 'array size
int angka;                  // input integer

string a1, a2, a3, a4, a5;  //store ascii line by line

cout << "Masukkan Angka : ";
cin >> angka;

int temp = angka;
while (temp != 0) {
    temp /= 10;
    count++;
}

arr = new int[count];

for (int i = count-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    arr[i] = angka % 10;
    angka /= 10;
}

for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    switch (arr[i]) {

    case 1: {
        a1 += "#   ";
        a2 += "#   ";
        a3 += "#   ";
        a4 += "#   ";
        a5 += "#   ";
        break; }
    case 2: {
        a1 += "###   ";
        a2 += "  #   ";
        a3 += "###   ";
        a4 += "#     ";
        a5 += "###   ";
        break; }
    case 3: {
        a1 += "###   ";
        a2 += "  #   ";
        a3 += "###   ";
        a4 += "  #   ";
        a5 += "###   ";
        break; }
    case 4: {
        a1 += "# #   ";
        a2 += "# #   ";
        a3 += "###   ";
        a4 += "  #   ";
        a5 += "  #   ";
        break; }
    case 5: {
        a1 += "###   ";
        a2 += "#     ";
        a3 += "###   ";
        a4 += "  #   ";
        a5 += "###   ";
        break; }
    case 6: {
        a1 += "###   ";
        a2 += "#     ";
        a3 += "###   ";
        a4 += "# #   ";
        a5 += "###   ";
        break; }
    case 7: {
        a1 += "###   ";
        a2 += "# #   ";
        a3 += "  #   ";
        a4 += "  #   ";
        a5 += "  #   ";
        break; }
    case 8: {
        a1 += "###   ";
        a2 += "# #   ";
        a3 += "###   ";
        a4 += "# #   ";
        a5 += "###   ";
        break; }
    case 9: {
        a1 += "###   ";
        a2 += "# #   ";
        a3 += "###   ";
        a4 += "  #   ";
        a5 += "###   ";
        break; }

    }
}

cout << a1 <<endl<< a2 << endl << a3 << endl << a4 << endl << a5 << endl;

return 0;
}
```

My English skill is beginner. Please understanding my write.
It is your style code. c++ is writing line by line.
input is 123,

1 line = #   ###   ###

2 line = #     #     #

3 line = #   ###   ###

4 line = #   #       #

5 line = #   ###   ###

and print (1 line \n)+---+(5 line \n).

This code is beginner level. I consider your coding skill. 
I hope it helps.

Comment: '123' is just an example. Answer should work for any given integer input.

Comment: Sorry,I mean that just example code. Update full code.